# OperationFailedException: Installation failed

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, apk

Im working on game develop in Unity. I want to make a game of Android. I downloaded the jdk, spk, etc.

I followed exacly how the videos told me but when I connect my Android to the game and click on "Build And Run" I get the error in the end of the process: Failed to build APK!.

The console shows:

> OperationFailedException: Installation failed. See the Console for
>   details.
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension.UploadAPK
>   (UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport buildReport,
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice device,
>   UnityEditor.ProgressTaskManager taskManager)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0
>   () UnityEditor.ProgressTaskManager.Run () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/ProgressBarUtils.cs:71)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension.LaunchBuildOnTarget
>   (UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport buildReport,
>   DeploymentTargetId targetId, UnityEditor.ProgressHandler
>   progressHandler)
>   UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetManager.LaunchBuildOnTarget
>   (BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport
>   buildReport, DeploymentTargetId targetId, UnityEditor.ProgressHandler
>   progressHandler) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/DeploymentTargets/DeploymentTargetManager.cs:36)
>   UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer+c__AnonStorey0.<>m__1 ()
>   (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:181)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why this error can appear. Here are the most **four** known reasons why this is happening(arranged from very likely to unlikely order):

**1**.Your *Minimum API Level* in Unity is set to a higher API level than the actual version of your device/phone.

Go to *Edit* --> *Project Settings* --> *Player* --> *Other Settings* --> *Identification* --> *Minimum API Level* then change that to match your OS version.

---

**2**.Unity is trying to install your apk in a location you don't have permission to write to.

Go to *Edit* --> *Project Settings* --> *Player* --> *Other Settings* --> *Configuration* --> *Install Location* then change that to *Automatic*.

If build doesn't work, try the `Prefer External` then `Force Internal`. If none of them worked, roll back to `Automatic` as that is recommended option.

---

**3**.There is already app with the-same package name installed on your device. Consider changing your package name.

Go to *Edit* --> *Project Settings* --> *Player* --> *Other Settings* --> *Identification* --> *Package Name* then change that to new name.

You can also remove/uninstall the app from your device first.

---

**4**.Your device hardware/peripheral

It is harder to fix this issue when **#1** to **#3** did not solve it. The problem is now likely your device or any peripherals you are using. Here are the possible reasons and fix:

**A**.USB cable. - Try another cable.

**B**.USB hub on your computer- Try another one on the computer.

**C**.Battery. - A defective battery can also cause this. If the battery is swollen then it extreme likely that this is the issue. Replace the battery if you notice this.

**D**. Corrupted storage. - This happens sometimes and it is the problem, perform hard reset on the Android device.

Comment: thank you very much !! i actually tried all 1-3 solutions, but none seem to work, but now i tried a different phone and it works like a charm !! ;) i guess there is a problem with my xiaomi ;S

Comment: Then it's your device hardware as #4 says. Either the Corrupted storage I mentioned or the hardware. Did you try the hard reset from 4D? It should work if not then hardware issue.